# Out of disk space on sbs2011

Tags: small-business-server

Scenario:
SO: SBS2011
HD: 186GB - Available space: 0
DIR and file greater than 1GB:

- /windows/winsxs -> 45,5GB
- /windows/installer -> 5,5GB
- /windows/assembly -> 2,5GB
- /unknown -> 113,9 GB

---

I tried:

- Disk cleaner, the tool claim to be able cleaning 18Gb of system file, but once started and run for some minutes it stops with no message.

  ### - dism /online /cleanup-image /spsuperseded with no success

Any tip?
thx

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for StackOverflow. You could check the help section of [super user](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) to see if it would be more suitable to be posted on there?

Comment: What I miss? Why this question should be off topics? Have you any suggestion about it?

Comment: StackOverflow is for posting about programming, not computer maintenance

Answer (score 1):

Start by deleting everything in C:\Windows\Temp and everything in C:\Users[Username]\Appdata\Local\Temp where [Username] is your domain admin account. Also delete all unnecessary accounts from C:\Users. Then reboot so that your virtual RAM file gets shrunk/removed.

Also yes, wrong section.

Comment: Already done, I get 200MB of free space just for  a few minutes then disappeared

Comment: disable all exchange services and everything else that can be disabled and still have the server boot, then reboot again. Or boot in safe mode. Also, you may have a virus if every scrap of free space gets immediately gobbled up.